# Solving the Rubik cube with given initial and target states (generalization of standard Rubik cube)

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, rubiks-cube

Consider the generalization of the Rubik cube problem, where we are given an initial state $A$ and a final state $B$, and we search for a path between the two.

We can easily show that given $A$ and $B$, one can compute $X$ such that the path from $X$ to $S$ is the same as the path from $A$ to $B$.  Here, $S$ denotes the standard solved state.

Now, is there a simple and convenient way to represent this isomorphism between the group subsumed by $A$ and $B$ and the group subsumed by $X$ and $S$?

Let $G_1$ be the group such that $A$ and $B$ are members of $G_1$. Accordingly, let $G_2$ be the group such that $X$ and $S$ are members of $G_2$. How to characterize the isomorphism between $G_1$ and $G_2$, which maps $A$ to $X$ and $B$ to $S$?

The isomorphism basically consists in recoloring the minicubes in $A$ to generate $X$ in  such a way that the solution (path) from $X$ to $S$ is the same as the solution from $A$ to $B$.  Note that we are able to compute $X$ without solving the Rubik cube problem, which is nice, because actually $X$ and $S$ may be in a different connected component than $A$ and $B$.

Correspondingly, we are searching for an isomorphism that does not require that $A$ and $B$ be in the same connected component as $X$ and $S$. Naturally, the isomorphism cannot rely on solving the Rubik cube, as the solution would forcefully require the four elements to be in the same connected component.

As an example, consider the following initial state $A$, depicted below,

[image: State A]

The goal is to find a path to state $B$, below

[image: State B]

This is equivalent to finding a path from state $X$ below to the canonical target state $S$

[image: State C]

How to describe, using the language of group theory, the isomorphism that maps $A$ into $X$ and that maps $B$ into the canonical target state $S$?

---

In what follows, we focus on the simplest case wherein $A$, $B$, $X$ and $S$ are all in the same connected component.   The possible configurations that we can get by manipulating a cube in configuration $A$ is the "orbit" of $A$.  So, we're saying that in what follows the orbit of $A$ (which includes $B$) must be the same as the orbit of $S$ (which includes $X$).

We can think about each configuration of the cube as being an alias to a sequence of moves that brings that configuration to the canonical solved state $S$.

Say that we refer to $M1$ as the sequence of moves that brings $A$ to the solved state $S$, and we refer to $M2$ as the sequence of moves that brings $B$ to the solved state $S$.

Then, the sequence of moves that brings $A$ to $B$ is

$M1 M2^{-1}$

and  $ A$ maps to $M1$ and $B$ maps to $M2$

in the same way that

$X$ maps to $M1 M2^{-1}$

and

$S$ maps to $M2 M2^{-1} $ which is the identity element.

Now, to build this mapping between $A$ and $X$ and between $B$ and $S$ we had to take the original sequence of moves and multiply each of those by $M2^{-1}$ (assuming operations are applied from left to right, otherwise, we would get $M2^{-1}M1$ as the mapping of $X$ instead of $M1 M2^{-1}$)

I'd be curious to know if there is an alternative way to represent that mapping, which does not rely on knowing the sequence of moves $M2^{-1}$. We can write a computer program to build $X$ from $A$ and $B$ without knowing $M1$ and $M2$, but I don't know how to represent the operator that this program is implementing using the language of group theory.

Is there an operator that maps states without necessarily sticking to the cube rules, but which allows to map $A$ into $X$ and $B$ into $S$ without knowing $M2$? I believe this operator is a sort of  exogenous or "out of band" operator in the group elements, leveraging side information about alternative representations of the elements of the groups.

Comment: Are you looking for standard cube notation?  Or a convention that is more general than cube notation?

Comment: @BrianTung any insight is welcome

Comment: If the sequence of moves $M_1$ brings the cube from $A$ to $S$ and the sequence $M_2$ takes it from $B$ to $S$, then the sequence $M_2^{-1}M_1$ (= $M_1$ followed by the inverse of $M_2$, where I use the convention of composing functions from right to left) takes it from $A$ to $B$. This is not necessarily the shortest sequence of move because there is no need for that sequence to go via $S$.

Comment: If you follow the convention (makes sense with Rubik's cube) of reading move sequences from left to right, then you may prefer writing it $M_1M_2^{-1}$.

Comment: thanks, @JyrkiLahtonen, indeed this is the "naive" solution, but we would like a solution that does not rely on the sequence of movements from B to S or from A to S to characterize the isomorphism, i.e., we would like to characterize the isomorphism without relying on the solution to the Rubik cube problem -- also, we would like a solution which works even if A and B are in a connected component different from X and S

Comment: Ok. So basically you want to recolor $B$ to look like $S$, map that recoloring to $A$, call it $A'$, then solve $A'\to S$, and then undo the recoloring?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen exactly!  it is not very difficult to write a program that does that, but I'm wondering how to represent this idea using group theory terminology

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ gotten by reassembling the pieces of a "legal" cube, or by some other process, like removing all the 54 stickers of $S$ and randomly permuting them. Undoubtedly you know that in the former case there are twelve connectivity components, and identifying them is easy. The latter would need a census of the orbits of the Rubik's group (or a variant thereof) in $S_{54}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen $A$ and $B$ are the inputs to the problem.  We are searching for $X$ (which you referred to as $A'$) such that solving for $X$ to reach $S$ also leads to a solution for $A$ to reach $B$.   While building $X$, given $A$ and $B$, we basically proceed in our computer program by writing the positions and orientations of the pieces in $X$ following your idea. Then, we use DeepCube (a deep neural network that solves the cube) to find the path from $X$ to $S$ and this is also a solution from $A$ to $B$. How to represent the algorithm to build $X$ in group theory terminology?

Comment: Sorry about creating confusion by not realizing that my $A'$ is your $X$. I need to reread your question a few times more to see what you are really asking :-)

Comment: But, just in case it matters, what set are $A$ and $B$ drawn from? For example, is it possible for $A$ to have a corner piece with three identically colored stickers (when $B$ obviously needs to have a similar corner piece), or is it, for example, known that $A$ and $B$ share the same set of small pieces with $S$, but possibly reassembled (a common way of getting "unsolvable" configurations with a physical cube), or something else?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thanks a lot! We are assuming the simplest setting: it is known that  and  share the same set of small pieces with , but possibly reassembled (a common way of getting "unsolvable" configurations with a physical cube) -- we are also assuming that $B$ is reachable from $A$

Comment: The process you are describing sounds like conjugation by an permutation that does not necessarily lie in the cube group. But I am nore sure what you mean by "the group subsumed by $A$ and $B$".

Comment: @DerekHolt thanks! please, may you help to elaborate? by "the group subsumed by $A$ and $B$"  we mean the group (in the group theory sense) wherein $A$ and $B$ lie, i.e., $A$ and $B$ are parts of a group -- let us denote this group by $G_1$ (I've updated the post accordingly)

Comment: @DerekHolt what do you mean by "conjugation by a permutation"?  If it does not lie in the cube group, where does it lie? How to define it?  It is OK if it lies in another group... I just want to understand how to write the isomorphism in mathematical notation... thanks again!

Comment: But $A$ and $B$ are states of the cube, not group elements. The group elements are the transformations from one state to another.

Comment: @DerekHolt is there a way to describe the group in a way that the elements are states of the cube? as the transformation from $A$ to $B$ is the same as the transformation from $X$ to $S$, there is no way to distinguish between $A$ and $X$? but if this is the case, in the language of group theory there would be no way to distinguish between the 12 connected components?